# Massive blank space to the right of all pages in Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice

My grandfather has been working on writing a book. All was going well until he called me to state that he has somehow messed up the file.

If you look at the image below, he has somehow added something to the right-hand side of all pages. Is it a table or something?

[image]

Does anyone know how to rectify this issue?

For anyone that would like to see the file itself, you can download it here: https://mega.co.nz/#!a9oHlK5Z!9xSCgCFJsmgTVKnqzJRGRsHOZM7cSBXV5bs_cW1Y6e4

Comment: So is he actually working in Word or OO (you tagged it with both)?  Also, it'd be good to know what you've tried already.  When you turn on reveal codes or go into a different view mode, is anything visible there?  Have you checked the page margin and page size settings?

Answer (score 7):

That's the margin that appears whenever Track Changes is on, or there are comments in the document. To hide it, in Word: `Review -> Track Changes -> No Markup`. In OpenOffice I believe it would be `View -> Comments` (Uncheck).

In Word 2016: `Review -> Show Comments`

Answer (score 0):

Activate 
`Openoffice:Menu > View > Ruler`

and you will see what you have got.

Turn it off with 
`Openoffice:Menu > View > Comment`